# Attempting to reach AWS Network Load Balancer leads to timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, jdbc, amazon-ec2, nlb

I have an internal (not Internet-facing) NLB set up in a VPC. The NLB routes to a target group containing only one target, and health checks are succeeding.

However, I am unable to make JDBC calls using the NLB's DNS. The NLB has a listener on port 10000 and I have EC2 instances running an application in the same VPC. When these EC2 instances attempt to make a JDBC call to jdbc:hive2://nlb-dns-name.com:10000/orchard, they time out trying to connect. I've logged into the EC2 instances and attempted to ping the NLB DNS record, which also times out.

Please let me know if there is something obvious I'm overlooking here. Thank you!

Edit: The EC2 instances' Security Groups allow all outbound traffic to the same VPC. The SGs of the NLB's target allow inbound traffic and the health check is passing. The NLB listens on port 10000 and routes to a target group containing the master node of one EMR cluster, which listens to JDBC connections on port 10000.

However, I'm reasonably sure the error is not in the NLB -> target routing, since the health checks pass. I believe the error is in the instance -> NLB due to the timeout, and i'm not sure if I'm doing that part correctly.

Comment: Since NLB doesn't have Security Groups, could you provide details of how you setup SGs for the instances? Also details for NLB listeners and target groups.

Comment: Will do, I'll add it in the post

Comment: Could you also clarify how you call the JDBC? You are calling NLB from the instances behind NLB? So you are trying to do the following: EC2 instance->NLB->same EC2 instance?

Comment: No, I am doing EC2 instance -> NLB -> EMR cluster's master node. I am attempting to open a Java SQL connection from the EC2 instance to jdbc:hive2://nlb-dns-name.com:10000/orchard. Previously, I routed to jdbc:hive2://{EMR cluster master's public DNS}:10000/orchard and this worked, but now to make routing easier and not have to hardcode the EMR master public DNS I want the connection to go through an NLB.

Comment: The EC2 instance is not registered with NLB? It is separate instance from NLB's target group?

Comment: Yes, separate instance from the target group but within the same VPC.

Comment: That's good. But I don't think you can connect internal NLB (no internet access) with a public DNS of EMR which requires internet access.

Comment: The NLB isn't connected to the public DNS, it's connected to the instance of the master node. As I've said in the post, the health check works so I can verify that the NLB -> EMR connection does work.

Comment: In my case it was that I selected default security group when creating the NLB instead of selecting my web-traffic security group. The default SG doesn't allow any port access from the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realized I never posted an update: the issue was that I was adding my targets by instance id. For some reason, when I added them by IP address, connections started being successful.

Comment: The most likely reason you see a difference between adding by instance-ID and adding by IP address is that security groups work differently in the two cases: when you add a target by instance-ID, the target's security group needs to allow connections *from the client* (the NLB is sort of "transparent" in this case: the networking rules can look "through" it to see the real source of the connection), whereas when you add a target by IP address, the target's security group needs to allow connections *from the NLB*.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. The internal network load balancer spans across two AZs and hence got two ENI. When the nlb DNS is resolved to one of the ENI IPs, it works fine but when it is resolved to other ENI IP, it doesn't work. This is strange.

Here's a sample call.

curl my-nlb-xxxxxxxxx.elb.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com
*   Trying 192.168.89.194:80...
* connect to 192.168.89.194 port 80 failed: Connection timed out
*   Trying 192.168.107.158:80...
* Connected to my-nlb-xxxxxxxxx.elb.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com(192.168.107.158) port 80 (#0)